# Do I need to overload the constructor | factory method for each combination of constructor's | factory method's arguments?

Tags: java, constructor, overloading, factory-method, constructor-overloading

I have 4 instance variables that can be initialized by default, is the code written below appropriate? The number of constructors is growing a terrible pace, will I use the [Builder object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) that have getters and setters?

```
 class Example {
    private int a;
    private String s;
    private Object object;
    private boolean aBoolean;


    public Example(int a1, String s1, Object object1, boolean aBoolean1) {
        a = a1;
        s = s1;
        object = object1;
        aBoolean = aBoolean1;
    }

    public Example(int a1, String s1, Object object1) {
        this(a1, s1, object1, true);
    }

    public Example(int a1, String s1) {
        this(a1, s1, new Object(), true);
    }

    public Example(int a1,boolean aBoolean1) {
        this(a1, "a String", new Object(), aBoolean1);
    }
// ...(for all other combinations)
}
```

Comment: Why would you need all those constructors? What is wrong with an all arguments constructor? Why would you need them for all possible combinations, are they even used?

Comment: You should only write the code that is useful to someone *now*. So only write those combinations of constructors that you actually need. If more are needed later, then add them later. And yes, using a Builder is a fine solution to prevent having to write a ton of constructors.

Comment: well, if you think there are going to be more variables you are going to be adding, its always good to refactor your code now to use a design pattern. If it was only a few variables, it would be a lot of boiler plate, so theres always a trade off. Of course, this is very opinion-based, so it ultimately is up to you

Comment: This looks like a good application of the [Builder Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern).

Comment: @M.Deinum if the class is public, then for the convenience of the end user of the class

Comment: How is plowing through 20 constructors easier then have 1 well documented one (or a few possible permutations with defaults). Also if every permutation is possible why even use a constructor, instead create a default no-args constructor and use setters to set the needed values (and initialize with defaults).

Comment: I probable need to use Build Pattern for more flexibility, thank you all

Comment: @M.Deinum Yes you're completely right, so instead of providing setters for the class itself, I want to create setters only for Builder object(the main class will be immutable)

Comment: Seconding Andy's advice regarding the builder pattern: you can keep a non-public constructor that accepts the `Builder` object itself, assigning fields from the builder. No more updating a lengthy constructor call, just add lines for handling a new field in the builder and target object. If you have a specific question regarding introducing the builder pattern into this code, then update/edit your question to clarify where you're stuck.

Comment: I'd like to add that you can just initialize the class variables to default values inline, and then you don't have to rely on constructors to set the defaults. The defaults will be overwritten when you set them through a constructor or otherwise, so you can have constructors with just a couple subsets of fields that you need.

Comment: @ZackPeterson it's buried in a comment, but "the main class will be immutable" suggests that your solution wouldn't work, since the fields would no longer be able to be `final`. It could work in a builder itself, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Essentially, no. As a concept this doesn't scale. In two ways.

## Why your style doesn't work

### Combinatory explosion

Imagine you have 6 fields, and they all have default values. That means you're creating 2-to-the-6 different constructors (64 constructors). Aside from the fact that this is nuts on its face and certainly unmaintainable, even if you decide to use some automated tooling or annotation processors to generate them, there's a 65536 limit to the number you can have due to class file limits.

### Type conflicts

Imagine you have 2 fields (`a` and `b`), and they all have default values. Both fields are of type `int`. You can't do it - the constructor that takes only `a` and leaves `b` at default value conflicts with the constructor that takes only `b` and leaves `a` at default value - both have the signature `YourType(int)`.

## The common solutions

### Left-to-right only

Instead of creating the combinatory explosion, only pad on. So, given a hypothetical class with 3 fields (`int a; int b; String c;`), you have 4 constructors:

- `()`
- `(int a)`
- `(int a, int b)`
- `(int a, int b, String c)`

In other words, a given 'field' is required if any field 'below it' is also provided. Then order your fields in a sensible order. This keeps the number of constructors you have managable (if they're *all* defaulted, 1+n, which is linear to the number of fields you have, instead of a fac(n) explosion). It's also more or less what java programmers expect, and it matches various other languages that work similarly.

### Only full-and-none

The only constructors that exist is the no-args one because various tools need it, and the all-args one.

### Sensible

Think about the API, about how code that uses your class would operate. Is there a limited set of common and obvious ways to construct it? If yes, write those constructors. By definition there is no way to tell which ones you should write given a list of field types - you need to explain exactly what your type represents and what it does, it's "in the eye of the beholder". API design has a whiff of artistry to it. You decide how you think it should be used.

### Builders

This is the true fire-and-forget works-for-every-situation solution. You write a builder. The nature of builders means that your API users (the code that invokes stuff on this class / on instances of this class) end up writing something like this.

```
// given:

class Bridge {
  int yearBuilt;
  int span;
  String name;
}

// do not construct like this:
new Bridge(1937, 1280, "Golden Gate");
```

The reason you don't build like that is not *just* because it makes it very tricky to make every argument optional. It's also that the call itself becomes unreadable. Is that a bridge built in 1937 with a max span of 1280 meters, or is that a bridge built in 1280 with a max span of 1937 meters? Can't tell from this call without having the javadoc or getting my IDE to highlight the names of those params.

instead, you make your library users write this:

```
Bridge.builder()
  .buildYear(1937)
  .maxSpan(1280)
  .name("Golden Gate")
  .build();
```

This has all sorts of advantages:

- Every parameter can be defaulted/optional without a `fac(n)` explosion - it's linear to the number of fields.
- You can create multiple alternate ways to specify a given field value. Perhaps `.buildDate(LocalDate.of(1937, 4, 19))` and also `.buildDate(1937, Month.APRIL, 19)` - if you really want that, at least it doesn't make the combinatory explosion effect even worse.
- Callers have readable code - now just looking at that code there's no chance I confuse span from build year.
- Later additions with defaults don't break existing code. Adding an non-defaulted thing - that's trickier.
- It is relatively common, so should be familiar to your average java coder.

The downside is that it's a *ton* of boilerplate to write a builder and all the boilerplatey methods that are needed to make it work (not *just* a 'setter' in the build class for every field, but also `builder()`, `build()`, a private constructor, and so on).

Project Lombok generates all that for you though: [`@Builder` documentation](https://projectlombok.org/features/Builder). Even if you can't use lombok / do not like it, the docs contain an example of the 'vanilla' version of what `@Builder` generates, which serves as example of how to do it on your own.